# How to disable page scroll while dragging draggable in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a draggable defined this way:

```
$("#drag_area a").live("mouseup", function() {

    var object = $(this);
    var class_array = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");
    element(object,class_array);
    return false;

}).draggable({
    containment: "#drag_area",
    grid: [44, 44],
    zIndex: 1000
}).each(function(i, item){    
});
```

When i drag an item of the type 'drag_area a', if i scroll the page while dragging it, the item exits from containment... It is not a desidered situation, so how can i avoid this? Can i disable page scrolling during dragging?

Comment: create a *container* for your draggable elements and make it `overflow: auto` so when you drag-drop, scroll will be remain in the container itself.

Comment: It's working perfectly, you saved the day. Thank you. If you convert the comment into a proper answer i'll accept it.

Comment: improvement ... change .live to .on if you use newer jquery 1.6+ because .live is deprecated

Comment: I'm stucked with an older version of jquery, so it stays as it is for now. Thank you for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be using all your draggable elements without any *container*, i.e. why when you **Drag-n-Drop** your elements the whole page scrolls due to dragging.

Instead of that do as:

```
<div class="dragWrapper">
   <!-- Place all your draggable elements here -->
</div>
```

set a `max-height` and `overflow` of the `dragWrapper` class as:

```
.dragWrapper {
   max-height: 400px;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Now when you **Drag-n-Drop** your elements, instead of your *body*, scroll will be inside the container only.

Hope that will do the trick for you(which already did ;).

Comment: Please tell me you didn't use "i.e." for "that is". Edit that immediately in this holy grail of all that is SO good

Answer (score 31):

I solved that problem with one line of css on dragging element `touch-action: none;`

Comment: Amazing solution. Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: this is perfect.

Comment: Unbelievable!!!

Comment: Please provide more context around your answer. What element did you apply that to, and explain why it solves the problem? Links to more information.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ArtyukhAlex/n9ubnf05/).
I've made it based on this SO question: [How to disable scrolling temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily)

Here is an excerpt:

```
function disableScroll() {
    if (window.addEventListener) // older FF
    window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
    window.onwheel = preventDefault; // modern standard
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = preventDefault; // older browsers, IE
    window.ontouchmove = preventDefault; // mobile
    document.onkeydown = preventDefaultForScrollKeys;
}

$("#draggable").draggable({
    start: function () {
        disableScroll();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. In the end, it seemed an overflow:auto; was enough.