# How do I prevent jQuery dragging from scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, draggable

I have two `div`'s when dragging from `div1` to  `div2`, the `div1` scrollbar will appear and keep extending all the way until I drag the element on `div2`. How can I prevent the `div` from extending when I drag the element inside? Whole the element I am dragging does not break?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
      <div id='external-events'>
        <h4>Draggable Events</h4>
        <div class="tooltipevent" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:#ccc;position:absolute;z-index:10001;">some event</div>
        <div class="tooltipevent" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:#ccc;position:absolute;z-index:10001;">some event</div>
        <div class="tooltipevent" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:#ccc;position:absolute;z-index:10001;">some event</div>
        <div class="tooltipevent" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:#ccc;position:absolute;z-index:10001;">some event</div>
        <div class="tooltipevent" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:#ccc;position:absolute;z-index:10001;">some event</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <hr>
      <div id="calendar"></div>
      //drop event here
    </div>
</div>
```

**Drag panel CSS and size**

```
#external-events {
  float: left;
  max-width: 260px;
  width: 260px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #eee;
  text-align: left;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  max-height: 400px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

**after dragging**

[image: After dragging]

**supposed to be like that after dragging**
[image]

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but if you want to keep a div from having a scroll bar, you can achieve this with CSS buy using `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: i added pictures. hope you can understand

Answer (score 0):

Try to *remove* `overflow-y: auto` and *add* `overflow: hidden` to your **`#external-events`**.

### Edit

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32396478/3230030) from Stack Overflow might help shed some light on how to use prevent jQuery from scrolling the page when using `draggable` elements. Without a working example, I'm not 100% sure this is what you're talking about, but hopefully it proves to be helpful.

### Edit 2

In the pictures you posted, it looks like it's scrolling the overflow on the `x-axis`. That means you'll want to add `overflow-x: hidden` to the **`#externalevents`** styling. You can keep the `overflow-y: auto` in your code.

Comment: i want to have a scroll bar for y axis. setting to overflow:hidden does not prevent the div from scrolling

Comment: Are you able to provide a working example on CodePen or JSFiddle?

Comment: i added pictures.i tried to add to jsfiddle but it doesnt work somehow.Removing `over-flow-y` will cause the element to extend the page if i have too many items inside. so i want to keep them inside a div only

Comment: @MVCnewbie See my updated answer. It looks like from your screenshot it's just overflow on the `x-axis`, so hopefully my answer helps. If applying it just to **`#externalevents`** doesn't work, try also applying it to one of the parent classes like **`.col-md-2`**.

Comment: HI matthew,thanks for helping. Setting it to visible does not prevent the element from dragging.it just hide the scroll bar only. what i want was to disabled the scrolling of X axis totally

Comment: Why did you set it to `visible`? See **Edit 2** in my answer that suggests using `overflow-x: hidden` on **`#externalevents`** or the parent container, or both. You may also need to set a `max-width`.