# why does the scrollbar scroll when I move the div down to the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('#aaa').draggable();
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#aaa {
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
}

.wrap {
    height: 2000px;
    position: relative;
    ;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div id='aaa'></div>
</div>
<link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

when I drag the div overflow the page, the scrollbar will scroll. How do I prevent it from scrolling

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable page scroll while dragging draggable in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395936/how-to-disable-page-scroll-while-dragging-draggable-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior and can be disabled by adding `scroll: false` option.
https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-scroll

```js
$('#aaa').draggable({
    scroll: false
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#aaa {
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
}

.wrap {
    height: 2000px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div id='aaa'></div>
</div>
<link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: This doesn't stop the Horizontal scrolling however

Answer (score 0):

You can add `overflow: auto` to the styling of the `.wrap` class, which will stop horizontal and vertical scrolling while dragging that element

```js
$('#aaa').draggable();
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#aaa {
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
}

.wrap {
    height: 2000px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div id='aaa'></div>
</div>
<link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try like this**

```
#wrap{width: 800px; height: 800px; position: absolute; overflow: scroll; background: red; }
```

$( "#aaa" ).draggable({ containment: '#wrap',scroll: false })

Comment: Thank you very much, but I want to know what does the attribute of scroll do.

Comment: It sets the selected div scroll behaviour to false

Comment: if I do not use jquery-ui, I make div draggable with original javascript, by 'mousedown', 'mousemove', 'mouseup', how do I prevent it from scrolling?